# Can I query how many likes a Facebook post has?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed a custom app to upload videos that will be used in a contest, the video with the most likes wins. Is there a way to keep track of these likes without further user intervention? I mean, the user uploads the video now, with a "like counter" thing, and the day the contest ends, I just query the most liked (o three most liked) video(s). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the likes for all the videos with [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/), then get the counts in your app code:

`SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (YOUR, VIDEO, IDS)`

Or if you have the post_ids instead of the video object_ids:

`SELECT post_id FROM like WHERE post_id IN (YOUR, POST, IDS)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ids of the posts? To get the number of likes for a Facebook post, you can do:
https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/likes

(From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Note that you must supply an access token for a user who has access to this post, or the posts must be public.